# La configuracion de nginx se rompe con el tiempo

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digitalocean

Tengo una app MEAN desplegada en un servidor nginx, en digitalOcean con un ubuntu 20.04,
lo que pasa es que yo dejo configurado el nginx puedo entrar usando el dominio del servidor pero después de un tiempo deja de servir y solo me permite entrar mediante la ip. He seguido step-by-step las guías de digitalocean y otras que he encontrado pero no consigo que esto quede sirviendo.
mi configuración de nginx es esta:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        root /var/www/html/gestorDeRiesgoHSE/backend/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name domain.com; # managed by Certbot

        location ^~ /public/assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires 12h;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass http://ip:3000;
        }
}
```

Comment: Indicas "desplegada en un servidor apache", no necesitas Apache.

Nginx recibe las peticiones en el puerto 80 (mediante el dominio correspondiente) y le pasa las peticiones a la App MEAN que está escuchando en el puerto 3000.

Entiendo que domain.com en tu servidor en producción corresponde al dominio real de la aplicación en producción.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: amigo, tu problema esta relacionada al Entorno de desarrollo, configuracion del servidor y sus aplicaciones esto no esta relacionado a un problema de Desarrollo y programación sobre un codigo. tu pregunta estaria mejor ubicada en https://serverfault.com/

Comment: hola amigo que pena escribi mal, no tengo nada de apache en el server. Muchas gracias publicare la pregunta en serverfault